# ORDER BY and WHERE mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

> This code doesn't work when add order by with where.

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY 'item_no' WHERE mainitem_id=".$_GET['cate_id'] ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ORDER BY at the END of your Query:

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE mainitem_id='".addslashes($_GET['cate_id'])."' ORDER BY item_no;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM items 
        WHERE mainitem_id='".$_GET['cate_id']."' 
        ORDER BY item_no";
```

But note that your code is vurnerable to SQL injections. Please fix that problem too. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE mainitem_id=".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['cate_id'])."ORDER BY 'item_no'" ;
```

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` will protect you from sql injection.

Get variables are more prone to sql injections.So do check http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$cate_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cate_id']); //or any proper similar function (mysqli recommended)
$sel = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE mainitem_id='$cate_id' ORDER BY 'item_no'";
```